# Firestore returns empty array for collection with documents

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Firestore structure that looks something like the following JSON:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "yCzd0CGyoS0L05vXIy8J": {
      "prop1": true,
      "collection1": {
        "5vXIy8JyCzd0CGyoS0L0": {
          "prop1": true
        },
        "XIy8JyCzd0CGyoS0L05v": {
          "prop1": true
        },
        "vXIy8JyCzd0CGyoS0L05": {
          "prop1": true
        }
      }
    },
    "zd0CGyoS0L05vXIy8JyC": {
      "prop1": true,
      "collection1": {}
    },
    "yoS0L05vXIy8JyCzd0CG": {
      "prop1": false,
      "collection1": {}
    }
  }
}
```

I need to get the ID of each document in the "data" collection. In Node.js, I am trying to use the following statement:

```js
const data = await firestore.collection("data").get();
console.log(data.docs);
```

However, it returns an empty array even though there are documents in the collection.
But when I try to get some particular document I get correct output.

```js
const data = await firestore.collection("data").doc("zd0CGyoS0L05vXIy8JyC").get();
console.log(data.data());
```

When I try to use the "Query builder" in Firestore with the path "/data", I get a "No query result" output.

I tried the same structure in a different Firebase project, and it works properly there. What could be causing it to work in one project and not in the other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh.. I believe that here is answer to my question: stackoverflow.com/a/52293378/6125779